# Как вывести индексы совпадающих элементов одномерного и многомерного массивов JavaScript

Tags: javascript

** Вот индекс одного элемента вывел, а вот второго и третьего?**

```
            const rows = result.length; 
            const columns = result[0].length;
             const letterArray2 = letterArray.length
            function getXYCoords(arr1, arr2) {
              const coordinat = [];
              for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
                for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
                  for (let i = 0; i < letterArray2; i++)
                  if (arr2[y][x] === arr1[i]) {
                    coordinat.push([y,x])
                    return coordinat;
                  }
                }
              }
              return null;
            }
        
        console.log(getXYCoords(result2, result));
```

Comment: При написании/редактировании поста есть кнопка "Фрагмент кода". Напишите там сниппет с работающим примером. Вам помогут намного быстрее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getXYCoords(arr1, arr2) {
  const coordinat = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < arr2.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < arr2[y].length; x++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr2[y][x] === arr1[i]) {
          coordinat.push([y, x]);
          //return coordinat;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //return null;
  return coordinat;
}
console.log(getXYCoords(['k'], [['s', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['j', 'k', 'l', 'y']]))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо за предложенное решение!

Comment: @StepanB Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.