# Как сравнить массивы и вывести индекс(совпадающего элемента из матрицы) в приведенном примере с помощью методов forEach и findIndex

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
function getXYCoords(arr1, arr2) {
  const coordinat = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < arr2.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < arr2[y].length; x++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr2[y][x] === arr1[i]) {
          coordinat.push([y, x]);
         
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return coordinat;
}
console.log(getXYCoords(['k'], [['s', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['j', 'k', 'l', 'y']]))
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347941

Comment: Конечно, извеняюсь, забыл поблагодарить человека!